# hide runtime exception in RabbitMQ listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, logback

I used some exception to reject the message in some cases that intentionally happened but shown the exception in the console which looks not alright for the first glance.

how can I hide that specific exception from logging on console/file

I'm Using spring-boot and the default loggers!

```
public static class UndispatchException extends 
       AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException{

    public UndispatchException() {
        super("Dispatch still looking for a driver");
    }

}
```

here the listner

```
@RabbitListener(queues = TEST_QUEUE)
public void handle(Dispatch in) {
    if(in.isRequeue()){
        log.debug("will reject the message");
        throw new UndispatchException();
    }
    log.debug("won't reject the message");

}
```

here is the log I want to hide it! which mandetory to have to requeue the message in some cases!

```
2018-05-15 18:41:11.494  WARN 2709 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.amqp.handleException.demo.DemoApplication.handle(com.amqp.handleException.demo.DemoApplication$Dispatch)' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:140) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:856) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:779) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:105) [spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:208) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1349) [spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:760) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1292) [spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1262) [spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1800(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:105) [spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1518) [spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: com.amqp.handleException.demo.DemoApplication$UndispatchException: Dispatch still looking for a driver
    at com.amqp.handleException.demo.DemoApplication.handle(DemoApplication.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor38.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar:4.3.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
```

Comment: simply not log it? but it looks really bad to do that in the first place

Comment: You have an exception which "does not look alright" and your solution is hiding it? Have you thought about... well, handling it?

Comment: @Eugene I don't log it! when you throw an certain exception to requeue the message normally it will be logged by jvm/logger

Comment: @Ben please read the question carefully, "exception in the console which looks not alright for the first glance"!

Comment: Other than it not being correct English (which might be why I don't understand what you mean) you are saying: You have an exception that is shown on the console. So I say: Why not fix the exception instead of trying to hide the output?

Comment: You are trying to treat the symptons, not the problem.

Comment: @Ben you're right I should say "shown", regarding the comments! I need the message to be requeued! similar when you want to rollback the transaction! you have to throw a runtime exception to rollback the transaction!

Comment: You need to show the actual log message that you want to suppress.

Comment: @GaryRussell I'll update the question to have an example and exception message to suppress!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your logging configuration, set the log level for

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler
```

to ERROR (that message is logged at WARN level).

With Spring Boot, you can simply add...

```
logging.level.org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler=ERROR
```

...to your application.properties (or .yml) file.

**EDIT**

If you wish to do something different (such as log certain exceptions) you can make a copy of the `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` and make changes in the `handleError()` method. The [code is here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java#L74).

You would then configure the listener container (or listener container factory) with your custom error handler.

Comment: you answered the question and I marked as answered but there is another implicit question, if we want to print something instead of the entire stacktrace !

Comment: You would need to replace the default error handler - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: awesome! I can simply extends the ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler and make my own logic!

Comment: Unfortunately, it has some private methods so not so easy to extend; I am fixing that. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/750

Comment: for now, I can copy the class itself and change the part we need it, thanks!

Comment: You can extend it, but you'll need to copy the `causeChainContainsARADRE()` method so you can call it from `handleError()`. It will be protected in the next version. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/750

Comment: Thanks! @Gary, there is one more thing you have to care about it in the next version as well. whyin handle error the type of throwable is ListenerExecutionFailedException, it should be same as the exception I throw it in the Listener. Imagine I have more cases to handle it in the  ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler!

Comment: No; user exceptions are always wrapped like that; use `getCause()`.

Comment: you saved alot of time! Thanks again

Comment: another question for you @Gary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115222/how-to-make-common-dead-letter-exchange-to-all-my-queues

Comment: This is not a good answer because the part which logs as `WARN` in `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` is using a logger and it is not throwing an exception so it is not possible to change the log level by adding this configuration into config file, the best way is to extend the `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler` class and change the log level as it is also mentioned in the class itself : `Log the throwable at WARN level, including stack trace. Subclasses can override this behavior`. you can then add your custom handler as errorHandler for your rabbit configuration.

Comment: How can we "configure the listener container (or listener container factory) with your custom error handler." using Spring? I can`t figure it out. @Gary Russell

Comment: `public void setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler errorHandler)`

Comment: I mean, can we do the same with connection error? "ERROR [com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler] (AMQP Connection 999.999.999.999:5672) An unexpected connection driver error occurred: java.net" thx @Gary Russell

Comment: It would be better if you ask a new question and include the full stack trace, but the error handler is not involved with connection problems, only listener problems.